# Drupal 7 display (not download) PRIVATE pdf files in new tab

Tags: pdf, drupal, download

I'am using D7 with private file system.

All pdf links are opened in new tab but drupal force the download and I can't display the pdf in the browser.

Is there a place where you can configure download/display for private files

Any idea?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It's the decision made primarily by the browser. Some time ago Drupal was setting headers that pretty much forced browser to download, namely `content-disposition`.

[Since 7.22 doesn't](https://drupal.org/drupal-7.22-release-notes), so if you have recent version it's no longer a Drupal issue.

You can use [`hook_file_download`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_download/7) to conditionally add headers to your response and try to make browser display instead of downloading.